# How do I speed up packaging of my WAR project in Maven 3.3.3?

Tags: maven, package, maven-3, war, maven-war-plugin

I’m using Maven 3.3.3.  I have a WAR project with a large number of static assets.  Frequently when building my WAR project (using “mvn clean install”), the project will take upwards of 15 minutes to build, even when only Java files have changed.  Below is my WAR plugin configuration.  Is there any way to speed up the building of the file?  I’m using the “in=place” and “useCache” options but to no avail …

```
                                    <plugin>
                                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <version>2.6</version>
                                            <configuration>
                                                    <useCache>true</useCache>
                                                    <workDirectory>${user.home}/${project.artifactId}/war/work</workDirectory>
                                            </configuration>
                                            <executions>
                                                    <execution>
                                                            <id>default-war</id>
                                                            <phase>verify</phase>
                                                    </execution> 
                                                    <execution>
                                                            <id>war-inplace</id>
                                                            <phase>package</phase>
                                                            <goals>
                                                                    <goal>inplace</goal>
                                                            </goals>
                                                    </execution>
                                            </executions>
                                    </plugin>
```

Here’s the output from the Maven WAR plugin if this gives any insight into how to speed things up

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [myproject] in [/home/Dropbox/sb_workspace/myproject/target/myproject]
[INFO] Dependency [Dependency {groupId=org.mainco.subco, artifactId=orders, version=84.0.0-SNAPSHOT, type=jar}] has changed (was Dependency {groupId=org.mainco.subco, artifactId=orders, version=84.0.0-SNAPSHOT, type=jar}).
[WARNING] File to remove [/home/Dropbox/sb_workspace/myproject/target/myproject/WEB-INF/lib/orders-84.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar] has not been found
[INFO] Dependency [Dependency {groupId=org.springframework, artifactId=spring-core, version=3.2.11.RELEASE, type=jar}] has changed (was Dependency {groupId=org.springframework, artifactId=spring-core, version=3.2.11.RELEASE, type=jar}).
[WARNING] File to remove [/home/Dropbox/sb_workspace/myproject/target/myproject/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar] has not been found
[INFO] Dependency [Dependency {groupId=org.springframework.security.extensions, artifactId=spring-security-saml2-core, version=1.0.0.RC2, type=jar}] has changed (was Dependency {groupId=org.springframework.security.extensions, artifactId=spring-security-saml2-core, version=1.0.0.RC2, type=jar}).
[WARNING] File to remove [/home/Dropbox/sb_workspace/myproject/target/myproject/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.0.RC2.jar] has not been found
[INFO] Dependency [Dependency {groupId=org.opensaml, artifactId=opensaml, version=2.6.1, type=jar}] has changed (was Dependency {groupId=org.opensaml, artifactId=opensaml, version=2.6.1, type=jar}).
[WARNING] File to remove [/home/Dropbox/sb_workspace/myproject/target/myproject/WEB-INF/lib/opensaml-2.6.1.jar] has not been found
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/Dropbox/sb_workspace/myproject/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [719348 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/Dropbox/sb_workspace/myproject/target/myproject.war
```

Comment: First how large is the resulting war file?

Comment: Michael-O has some very good suggestions.  Additionally: what happens if you build *OUTSIDE* of your "Dropbox" folder?  I would strongly discourage you from *ever* doing builds there...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `${user.home}` is on a local disk, you can do the following:

1. Load off your assets in a module which is built as a JAR. Depent on that and serve those resources from the JAR. If you happen to use the Spring Framework, this comes for free or with Tomcat 7+ with `META-INF/resources`.
2. Some time ago, a fellow Maven committer advertised a [highly-concurrent version of the Plexus Archiver](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-dev/201501.mbox/%3CCAJZRQKw6iZaWao_faWpNKCNVqu41K9ZpEGoTuKdtDg62C70DsA@mail.gmail.com%3E) which is used to build WAR files with Maven. You may try this one.

Comment: Regarding your plexus-archiver idea, since I'm using version 2.6 of the WAR, isn't your dependency already included?  I'm reading "This is fixed in the maven-war-plugin version 2.4 (and you don’t need the explicit plexus-archiver dependency anymore), see related issue" from here -- http://mindthegab.com/2013/06/20/maven-is-not-so-evil-plexus-archives-2-3-is-a-life-saver-for-the-speed-of-your-war-development-with-maven/ .

Comment: @Dave The artice is ages old and not about concurrency but about `chmod`. I have updated my answer with a link.

Comment: I added those two dependencies into my war-plugin <dependencies> section, but sadly got the error, "Error assembling WAR: Problem creating war: /Users/davea/my_workspace/myproject/target/myproject/webapp/js/ckeditor3.6.4/skins/kama/templates.css (Too many open files)" when I ran "mvn clean install -DskipTests".

Comment: Repackaging the CKEditor? I was member of that group years ago and wrote the very first Java backend implementation for FCKeditor. Anyway, check `ulimit` first and `lsof` of the running process of Maven/JVM. Are you able to create a selfcontained test project for that? A ticket in Plexus Archiver might resolve it if is an issue with that. Anyway, I would still strongly advise to package the CKEditor as a JAR *once* and depend on it.

Comment: To clarify your point about packaging things into a JAR, how woudl we do that without having to change the paths in our HTML/JSP files?  If it does require chaning of the paths, I'll have a hard time convincing the team as there are thousands of files.

Comment: @Dave You are absolutely certain that you have added the correct dependency (versions) to make use of this feature? If in doubt, you might post this to the Maven Users Mailing List. How to avoid changing paths? First of all, I need to know which servlet container you use and do you use Spring Framework (which has `mvc:resources`). This will solve this issue. Ultimately, you can rewrite URLs up front with Tuckey's URL Rewrite. They should do. Important to know that those JARs should be build with your projects because they do not change often.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I have about 1200 Java classes. Packaging time is better with configuration

```
<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
<archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
```

My intuition tells that there should be no difference. But time of package phase is better (37 vs 17 seconds)